# How to send push notifications to users for a Google Assistant Action?

Tags: actions-on-google

I have created a Trivia Game for Google Assistant Action using the Trivia Game template. Can I send push notifications to users for my action? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

No the trivia game template does not provide capabilities like push notifications. To use that in your Action you'll want to create a custom [conversational Action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview) with [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/notifications).